# Telerik RadGridView insert new row MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

I have a RadGridView inside my view and I am binding its ItemSource to a list inside my ViewModel. Everything works fine. But how do I insert a new row with a MVVM approach. I would rather not use code-behind for that.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" Grid.Row="1" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lieferadressen}" ColumnWidth="*" />
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

I can't find anything on the Telerik documentation about inserting new rows with MVVM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own and I am gonna post my answer for those struggling with it.

So the basic approach is to use Interaction Triggers. For which you have to add the `System.Windows.Interactivity` package to your project via NuGet.

Then add the follwing 2 namespaces inside your xaml file which contains your RadGridView:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then you configure your RadGridView with the Triggers.

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView" Grid.Row="1" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsFilteringAllowed="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Lieferadressen}" ColumnWidth="*">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnded">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnLieferadresseRowEditEnded" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

The `EventName` is important here.

Then in your ViewModel:

```
public void OnLieferadresseRowEditEnded(object sender, GridViewRowEditEndedEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.Row as GridViewRow;

    if (e.EditAction == GridViewEditAction.Cancel)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (e.EditOperationType == GridViewEditOperationType.Insert)
    {
        //Insert the entry in the data base
    }
    else if (e.EditOperationType == GridViewEditOperationType.Edit)
    {
        //Update the entry in the data base
    }
}
```

Comment: The `System.Windows.Interactivity` package is deprecated. Use `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` instead. There is also no need for two namespaces (`i` and `ei` above). Instead, just include the `Behaviors` namespace in your XAML.